# To add a user with a roster in the create user Rest API

Tags: api, rest, xmpp, openfire, xmppframework

I have successfully created user using the create user API. And also I have added a roster for that user using a different API.Below mentioned two URLS

http://example.org:9090/plugins/restapi/v1/users

http://example.org:9090/plugins/restapi/v1/users/testuser/roster

Does the create user or any other API support both the above things together..Is there any API that takes the roster name as a parameter as well while adding the user, and does both the things create user and its roster??
Any suggestions will be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to create a user and create user roster entries in one request.
You need to create a user at first and later add entries over the second request.

ps: I'm the developer from the Openfire REST API plugin